# How to change a string if the variable is greater than the current

Tags: batch-file, ping

I made this code to check the ping before playing and it happens when the value changes from both the lower 2 digits when the higher ping ping stop correctly detect the changes.

If someone can give me a light thank.

```
@Echo Off

Title .Bat
Color 1f

FOR /F "tokens=6* delims==, " %%A in ('ping -n 2 br.leagueoflegends.com ^|find "="') do (Cls & Set MaiorPing=%%A & Set MenorPing=%%A & Set PingAtual=%%A)

:Pinges

FOR /F "tokens=6* delims==, " %%A in ('ping -n 2 br.leagueoflegends.com ^|find "="') do (Cls & Set PingAtual=%%A)

if /i %PingAtual% LEQ %Menorping% Set Menorping=%PingAtual%
if /i %PingAtual% GTR %Maiorping% Set Maiorping=%PingAtual%

Echo Current ping: %PingAtual%
Echo Lower ping: %Menorping%
Echo Higher ping: %Maiorping%

goto pinges
```

Comment: what's the actual output from `ping -n 2 br.leagueoflegends.com |find "ximo ="` ? this not working for me and I'm not sure if it's because of language settings (mine are en-us)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to fix it ... already patched. (Yes it is because of language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem are the comparisions. As you are not removing the `ms` suffix from the data, the `GTR` and `LEQ` operands are handling strings not numbers, so, `10ms` is less than `2ms`

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    title .Bat
    color 1f

    set "target=br.leagueoflegends.com"

    set "lowPing=9999"
    set "highPing=0"

:doPing    
    set "ping="

    for /f "tokens=9" %%a in ('
        ping -n 2 "%target%" ^|find "ms,"
    ') do for /f "delims=m " %%b in ("%%a") do set "ping=%%~b"

    cls

    if not defined ping  (
        echo No response
        goto :doPing
    )

    if %ping% gtr %highPing% set "highPing=%ping%"
    if %ping% lss %lowPing%  set "lowPing=%ping%"

    echo Current: %ping%   Max: %highPing%   Min: %lowPing%

    goto :doPing
```

Added an aditional `for` to separate the numeric data from the units.